Can I Date This Woman?
So, I'm 46 years old and browsing a dating site. This woman's profile has no photo, but it has me interested in a date with her. However, it just says that she is "under 100". Is she within my limit (+/- 10 years)? I pasted some of her profile below.
Can you help me figure it out?

About Me
Say a few words to introduce yourself. What makes you stand out from the crowd?
Hi, I am Nicky Julian and, well, I'm definitely not "normal", whatever that means, but who is? And would that even be a good thing? I'm not claiming to be unique or even particularly powerful, but I'm not weird or narcissistic or anything. Overall, I'm definitely happy, and that is what matters.
How important to you is wearing the latest fashion and/or popular makeup/hair style?
In a world full of pretense, I am proud to be the chick who keeps it real, natural and practical, so I rarely wear makeup and cannot justify the cost of keeping up with the latest fashion.
Do those you know see you as amicable?
Many have described me as friendly, yet none have specifically used the term amicable.
Are you good at managing money?
Haha! You just HAD to ask that, didn't you? If I'm being honest, some might call me extravagant, but I prefer to say that I'm just not frugal. Life is short. Live a little and enjoy it!
Do you still consider yourself "in your prime"?
I'll only say that life goes on and those around me see me as one who stays positive and is never negative.
Would you consider yourself lucky?
No, but who needs luck when one is perfect!? Lol
Could someone persuade you to do a solo camping trip overnight?
Umm, no way! While I am always rational and can be convinced with good, logical points, I am not a solitary creature, and couldn't survive a night alone.

Unfortunately for you...

She is out of your age range as she is, quite literally, 28

Here's why:

The entire bio is actually about the properties of the number 28:

- 28 is a 'happy' number , but not a 'unique', 'powerful', 'weird', 'normal' or  'narcissistic' number
- It is 'real, natural' and a 'practical' number
- It is a 'friendly' number but not an 'amicable' number
- It is an 'extravagant' number but not a 'frugal' number
- It is obviously positive and not negative, but also not a prime
- It is not a 'lucky' number, but it is a 'perfect' number
- It is always rational, and not a 'solitary' number

And on top of that, 'Nicky Julian' is a reference to Nickel - Element 28 and the Julian calendar - which follows a 28 year cycle!

Thanks @Stiv and @Auride for catching some of the ones I missed!

Probably missed some more things so feel free to point them out!

Additional ones I spotted include rot13(jrveq, anepvffvfgvp, rkgenintnag, yhpxl naq fbyvgnel, nyy bs juvpu ner fvzvyne frdhraprf)

I think these make all of them:
28 is not a normal number, because it has a finite number of digits;
It is not weird, because it is perfect;
It is not narcissistic, because 2^2+8^2 =/= 28;
It forms "friendly pairs" with any other perfect number;
It is extravagant (the opposite of frugal);
It is not a solitary number (a number without friendly pairs).

@Stiv just got the L one, was focused too much on what it is rather than what its not! Thanks for the extras!

@Auride thanks for catching weird, had missed that! I'll look into friendly too

I made a spreadsheet, and all you really need are "Sevraqyl"m "Cresrpg", and the given of less than 100. Everything after that is redundant.

Alas, she's a little too young for you even using the traditional (if rather weird and creepy according to today's sensibilities) "half your age plus seven" rule.

The "perfect" part gave it away for me. It would have been more hip to be square (36 or 49).
